# Show that the function is discontinuous at c=2 using delta epsilon

Tags: functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am struggling with discontinuity and continuity.

```
f(x)= {-1, x<2
        0, x=2 
        1, x>2
```

I realize that I must show that $\exists$ $\epsilon$ > 0 s.t. $\forall \delta >0$, $\exists x$, |x-2|<$\delta$ and |f(x)-0|>$\epsilon$.

I just do not know where to go from there!

I realize also you choose an epsilon, but am lost as to what to do with the delta.

Any suggestions would be great, but preferably the actual proof. I am lost on this problem and do not have any examples that have helped so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider that if you choose an epsilon less than one-half, you could take any delta greater than zero and find function values that are greater than the epsilon simply by taking values near 2 but not at 2.

Comment: I chose $\epsilon$ = 1/2 actually, but does that mean that I don't have to make a relationship between epsilon and delta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I realize that I must show that $\exists$ $\epsilon$ > 0 s.t. $\forall \delta >0$, $\exists x$, |x-2|<$\delta$ and |f(x)-0|>$\epsilon$.

Right.  To prove this is true, we need to show there exists such an epsilon, so it suffices to prove it for $\epsilon = \frac12$.  Then fix $\delta > 0$, we need to show that there is some $x$ such that $|x - 2| < \delta$ and $|f(x)| > \epsilon$.  To show *this* is true, we can just need to show it is true for some $x$, so choose $x = 2 + \frac{\delta}{2}$...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!